# Widgets don't respond when re-added through code

Tags: android, android-widget, launcher

I am working on a launcher. It let's users add widgets from the list, it works fine.
I store information about the widget (PackageName, ClassName and it's co-ordinates on the screen) in my database when the user adds one to the screen.

When the application is restarted (or the device itself) I add those (user selected) widgets back through code:

```
// APPWIDGET_HOST_ID is any number you like
appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
appWidgetHost = new AppWidgetHost(this, APPWIDGET_HOST_ID);
AppWidgetProviderInfo newAppWidgetProviderInfo = new AppWidgetProviderInfo();

// Get an id
int appWidgetId = appWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();

// Get the list of installed widgets
List<AppWidgetProviderInfo> appWidgetInfos = new ArrayList<AppWidgetProviderInfo>();
appWidgetInfos = appWidgetManager.getInstalledProviders();

for(int j = 0; j < appWidgetInfos.size(); j++)
{
    if (appWidgetInfos.get(j).provider.getPackageName().equals(PackageName) && appWidgetInfos.get(j).provider.getClassName().equals(ClassName))
    {
        // Get the full info of the required widget
        newAppWidgetProviderInfo = appWidgetInfos.get(j);
        break;
    }
 }

// Create Widget
AppWidgetHostView hostView = appWidgetHost.createView(this, appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo);
hostView.setAppWidget(appWidgetId, newAppWidgetProviderInfo);

// Add it to your layout
RelativeLayout widgetLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.widgetLayout);
widgetLayout.addView(hostView);
```

The widget is successfully added to the layout but it seems like it's not enabled/updated. It doesn't respond to clicks (for instance, Analog Clock) and doesn't show any data (for instance, Music player widget), although I have put this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    appWidgetHost.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    appWidgetHost.stopListening();
}
```

I am stuck on it since quite a long time. Searched a lot but it seems I'm the only one in this world with this problem.

Comment: have you ever solved your problem, I am having a similar one look at my latest question..

Comment: Not yet, I've put that on hold while I'm busy with the other things. I'll surely post the solution as soon as I get one. :/

Comment: Any further news on this??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. :(

Comment: Yes, I finally got the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can invoke a dialog asking user to permit our app to be able to bind widget IDs with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, sSavedWidgetId);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER, mWidgetInfo.provider);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BIND_WIDGET);
```

And bind widget IDs to make them actually work with:

```
Bundle opts = new Bundle();
opts.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH, maxWidth);
opts.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT, minHeight);
opts.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH, maxWidth);
opts.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT, maxHeight);

widgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(widgetId, mWidgetInfo, opts);
```

For more information refer:

- [AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND)
- [AppWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(int,%20android.content.ComponentName))

I wish someone would have answered the same 5 years ago.

Comment: I'm having similar problems, can I ask you some questions?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Can I contact you privately email, facebook or other?

Comment: Nice Solution 

Comment: I know this is old, but REQUEST_BIND_WIDGET cannot be resolved. What am I overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: The second param you pass in `startActivityForResult()` method is an integer for your reference that gets passed back in `onActivityResult()` method on completion of the process. It's just a custom variable which you can replace with any unique integer of your choice.