# Is it possible to add widget of some other app to home screen programmatically?

Tags: android, widget, home-screen-widget

I wanted to add a widget for a targeted app which is present in the device from my app to home screen programmatically.

Tried some things but not working

Comment: Do you have to pin the other app from your app in the widget?

Comment: I need to pin another app's widget from my app to homescreen @TippuFisalSheriff

Comment: Can you give more clarity, You need to pin other apps or have to ping other app widget's data.

Comment: As different apps have some widgets defined for eg. in chrome we have : QuickActionSearchWidget.
So is there a way to pin this widget from my app to homescreen.
@TippuFisalSheriff

Comment: Adding more for clarity : Is it possible to add another app's widget to homescreen from my app programmatically.
@TippuFisalSheriff

Comment: I think is not possible, do you have any approach to receive mobile apps widgets data ?

Comment: Yes we can get all the widgets which are installed on device by : appWidgetManager.installedProviders
@TippuFisalSheriff

Comment: Okay, can attach the document here, that you referred to get the details

Comment: I have referred these steps : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847824/android-adding-widgets-to-app-programmatically-warning-message) but with this I am able to set the widgets on my app, not on Home screen.
For Home screen we need to call requestPinAppWidget which is supported in Android O and above. 
With this requestPinAppWidget method I am able to set my app's  widgets to home screen. But I want to set other app's widgets to home screen.
Think I am missing here something

Comment: Check with issue tracker, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=requestPinAppWidget